# Is "encapture" a word?

Tags: etymology, verbs, is-it-a-word, prefixes

I always thought that "**encapture**" is a word meaning **"to capture"**. However, spellchecking softwares flag this term and a quick Google search shows that this term is not listed in any dictionary except **Wiktionary**:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/encapture

The only instance that I found of its usage in a credible text is a poem by **Kavanagh** called **Canal Bank Walks**:

> *Leafy-with-love banks and the green waters of the canal
>
>   Pouring redemption for me, that I do
>
>   The will of God, wallow in the habitual, the banal,
>
>   Grow with nature again as before I grew.
>
>   The bright stick trapped, the breeze adding a third
>
>   Party to the couple kissing on an old seat,
>
>   And a bird gathering materials for the nest for the Word
>
>   Eloquently new and abandoned to its delirious beat.
>
>   O unworn world enrapture me, **encapture** me in a web
>
>   Of fabulous grass and eternal voices by a beech,
>
>   Feed the gaping need of my senses, give me ad lib
>
>   To pray unselfconsciously with overflowing speech
>
>   For this soul needs to be honoured with a new dress woven
>
>   From green and blue things and arguments that cannot be proven*

**So is it correct to use this term?** By "correct" I mean whether I can use it in normal sentences. The reason I cited this poem is because this is the only example I found where "encapture" has been used in a credible text. But I've also seen it being used numerous times in verbal casual communications. I'm a non-native speaker, and have heard other people use it so I always assumed it's a legit word.

Comment: By "correct" I mean whether I can use it in normal sentences. The reason I cited this poem is because this is the only example I found where "encapture" has been used in a text. Im a non-native speaker, and have heard other people use it so I always assumed it's a legit word.

Comment: It's in [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/encapture), but it isn't in the Oxford English Dictionary.  The poet used it because it fit with enrapture...enrapture me, encapture me.  As to whether you should use it in normal conversation -- my advice is not to use it in a job interview, but go ahead with someone you know well and want to know better.  You can always blame it on the poem; if so, best to memorize some lines from the poem.

Comment: It sounds just as acceptable as 'Eloquently new and abandoned to its delirious beat.
O unworn world enrapture me' ie you'd probably get thrown out of a pub (or everyone else would leave). But the Poets Society would love it.

Comment: What do you even mean by "***encapture** is a word meaning **to capture***". If anything, *capture* is a word meaning *to capture*. Are you asking whether *encapture* is a synonym for *capture*?

Comment: @Drew The wiktionary definition says that encapture means "to capture"

Comment: If you do a search on Google Books (not ordinary Google) you'll find several more uses of *encapture*. You'll also come across an entry for the prefix *en* in *The Oxford Reference Guide to English Morphology*. It's a viable prefix than can be attached to *capture*, though it's not in the OED and most uses are either poetic or geek-talk. So yes it's a word. But outside of the aforementioned contexts it's not used by native speakers.

Comment: One should never consider a spell checker to be an "authority" on what is or isn't a "real word".  The purpose of a spell checker it to help you avoid egregious spelling mistakes, and a red underline or whatever does not mean that the word is *wrong*, only that it *suspect*, and you should double-check what you've written.  (The same goes for syntax checkers.)

Comment: This is all just a matter of opinion. In the opinion of the full OED (probably the most authoritative source), ***encapture*** isn't even a word at all. But you argue with creative poets at your peril, and it seems to me ***en-*** and ***em-*** are still "productive prefixes". In which context I'd like to share the fact that I've just discovered ***embiggen*** dates back to at least 1884 - for decades I've always assumed it was coined by The Simpsons in *A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man.*

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to be a mutation of the word 'Encapsulate'.

To express the essential features of (someone or something) succinctly.
"the conclusion is encapsulated in one sentence"
synonyms:   summarize, sum up, give the gist of, put in a nutshell; capture, express
"their conclusions are encapsulated in one sentence"

Answer (score 0):

As was said in the comments, **encapture** is not in the Oxford English
Dictionary:

http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?filter=dictionary&query=encapture

So I would say at least in that context that it is not a word.

Answer (score -1):

I heard a woman use enrapture the other day referring to a museum piece but I have never heard of encapture so I do not think it used in modern day English. However,
(the great word of doubt) it might have been used in old English but it is really not relevant for today.